# Transfer removed <li> items into another <ul> list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Array 'myPicks' has a unique list of classes (.scifi, .adventure, etc.) , which will be used for sorting.

There is also an unordered list with li items, all with the class '.possibleMatch'

I am using variable 'camel' to filter through all of these '.possibleMatch' li's using the following:

```
var camel = $('.possibleMatch').not(myPicks.join(','));
```

Now, once I call camel,

```
 camel.html(camel).html();
```

the HTML updates with an unordered list with only li items with the classes specified in 'myPicks'.

This is working as I had hoped, but now I am stuck on how to move all the **removed** li items into another unordered list, that goes under the original unordered list.

I've tried

```
var noLonger = $('.possibleGames').filter(myPicks.join(','));
$('#somewhatMatch').html(noLonger.html(noLonger).html());
```

to try to move the removed items to a new unordered list, #somewhatMatch, but to no avail, now the original list will only show li items **without** the classes specified in 'myPicks'.

Please help!

--

Code that worked, if anyone uses this obscure question in the future:

```
//not sure why, but must clone beforehand
var llama = camel.clone();
//the following updates the original ul with items that match criteria
camel.html(camel).html();
//the following moves unmatched items into a new ul
$('#somewhatMatch').append(llama);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
var noLonger = $('.possibleGames').filter(myPicks.join(','));
$('#somewhatMatch').empty().append(noLonger.clone());
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I had to tweak your code a bit, but it works now.